# Entering a place where Gentiles and Jews Daven together from a Siddur

Tags: halacha, tefilla, gentiles, synagogue

Would it be permitted to pray in a place where there are services that are mixed with Jews and gentiles? Meaning, a synagogue that also invites gentiles to pray with the Jews (but they all pray from a Sidur).

Comment: Need more details on what you are talking about.  You mean like a shul that allows non-Jews to visit?  A place where non-Jews are learning to convert?

Comment: Is this a specific denomination of Judaism, you're talking about? Is it an interfaith service?  Bnei Noah?  Please clarify.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to specify more what you're talking about. (If your question really is a blanket "If there are any gentiles in a synagogue, does that invalidate the entire synagogue?" please make that clear.) Also, please add information about why you suspect the problem you're referring to (to be specified) could be a problem.

Comment: I can not tell if the question has been improved or not. Are you asking "If all else is equal, can I enter a place where gentiles are praying with Jews vs a place where only Jews are praying?"  Or are you asking, "Are you allowed to let gentiles pray in a place that Jews pray?"

Comment: Are you asking whether it would be permitted to pray in the Beit Hamikdash?

Comment: Does the synagogue allow anyone to walk in without determining their ethnoreligious status?  (i.e. almost all synagogues) or was there a specific, publicized "interfaith" invitation made for specific Gentiles to join the service?  (If it's the latter, I think my original answer still applies.)

Comment: They invite everyone (including gentiles).

Comment: @IsaacMoses a certain very famous place that I don't want to say the name of.

Comment: @HachamGabriel OK, at this point, I'm prepared to 1) Re-open the question. 2) Delete Will's answer. 3) Add an answer along the lines of "I've never heard of a shul that checks whether people coming in are Jewish or not, turning away those who aren't, so it must be allowed." Would that be a relevant answer? If not, the question requires more specification.

Comment: I still have a question - is this some form or outreach, or are they just open and known as a place where people from all walks of life come to pray together?

Comment: @HachamGabriel why won't you say the name of the place?  The kotel?  A specific synagogue?

Comment: @Will hasash lashon hara

Comment: @SethJ your second option

Comment: I don't know why it would be a problem. See my comment on Isaac's answer. I didn't know where else to put my comment, so I just stuck it there. I didn't want to stick it here lest it appear to be criticism of the question, which it was not intended to be.

Comment: @HachamGabriel do the people who run this place try to hide the fact that Gentiles come to pray?  Do they not want people to talk about it?  If they're open about it, if they're happy or even indifferent about it, it's not lashon hara - and certainly if it's already publicly known that this is a normal occurrence in this place, it's not lashon hara.  In any case, it's impossible to answer this question without a specific place, because the answer will be different based on which specific place you mean.

Answer (score 7):

I've never heard of a synagogue that checks whether people coming in are Jewish or not, turning away those who aren't, so allowing Jews and gentiles to pray together is presumably not forbidden, and therefore, entering a building in which this happens is presumably also not forbidden.

In fact, given that gentiles were invited to bring certain kinds of offerings to the Temple, and entering the Temple certainly wasn't forbidden (at least, not for that reason!), it would stand to reason that synagogues that behave similarly would be treated similarly.

Comment: +1, but: Re "I've never heard of a synagogue that checks whether people coming in are Jewish or not": I can't find it now, but someone once mentioned in a comment on this site that his local synagogue has a guard that stops anyone who looks like he doesn't belong and ascertains (I don't know how) that he's Jewish before allowing him in. (This, to foil terrorists.)

Comment: @msh210, Jewish facilities in Europe , including synagogues, tend to have guards who do what you say. (I've seen this myself in Paris.) However, as you indicate, the purpose is to filter out potential attackers, not for any Halachic reason. The test would be whether a gentile who comes in the company of a trusted member would be allowed to enter, and I strongly suspect that he/she would be.

Comment: This is not to critique your answer, nor the question, but I just want to put it somewhere and it's certainly not a better answer than yours, so I'm just tacking it here if you'll forgive me.  I just want to add that I have been to many a family occasion in Shul (B' Mitzvah, etc.) with non-Jewish friends invited, and I've never seen any turned away.  I've also seen many prospective Gerim in attendance. All generally pick up a Siddur, if not to actually Daven, then at least to follow along, although the prospective Gerim tend to Daven.