# Yishayahu 56:7 – what is ביתי?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, synagogue, beis-hamikdash, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Inspired by the first comment [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40950/can-a-gentile-pray-in-a-synagogue).

Yishayahu 56:7 reads ([Mechon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1056.htm)):

> וַהֲבִֽיאוֹתִ֞ים אֶל־הַ֣ר קָדְשִׁ֗י וְשִׂמַּחְתִּים֙ בְּבֵ֣ית תְּפִלָּתִ֔י עוֹלֹֽתֵיהֶ֧ם וְזִבְחֵיהֶ֛ם לְרָצ֖וֹן עַֽל־מִזְבְּחִ֑י כִּ֣י בֵיתִ֔י בֵּית־תְּפִלָּ֥ה יִקָּרֵ֖א לְכָל־הָֽעַמִּֽים׃

Does ביתי refer to the Beit haMikdash or to batei knesset (synagogues)?

Comment: Is there only one Beit Keneset? Also, given the sacrificial and Temple Mount imagery in the first half of the verse, why would you think ביתי isn't referring to the Temple?

Comment: Have you checked any commentaries on this verse to see what they have to say? Which?

Comment: It is obviously about the Temple

Comment: @DoubleAA, I figured, but Ray's comment inspired me to ask the question, even though it is clearly referring to B"M, rather than schuls.

Comment: Should we understand "refer to" as "also apply to" then?

Answer (score 1):

[Targum Yonasan](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.56.7?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=Targum%20Jonathan%20on%20Isaiah&lang2=he) translates "בֵיתִ֔י" as: "בֵית מַקְדְשִׁי" which shows that he understands it as being the Beis haMikdash